# Assinging filename to a variable in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

In excel msoFileDialogFilePicker will return a file name along with its path all I want is the file name. Here is the code that returns both:

```
Sub GetfileNames()

Dim fd As FileDialog


dialogTitle = "Select files for Master Update."

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant


With fd
    .InitialFileName = "H:\Desktop\Workforce Project Documents\Update Sandbox\"
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Filters.Clear
    .Title = dialogTitle
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails

'This MSG is displayed if the user dose not select a file
        If .Show = False Then
            MsgBox "Files not selected to update. Process Terminated"
            Exit Sub
        End If

    'vrtSelectedItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    'vrtSelectedItem = Right(vrtSelectedItem, Len(vrtSelectedItem) - InStrRev(vrtSelectedItem, "\"))


    For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems

        MsgBox "Selected file's name is: " & vrtSelectedItem
        'MsgBox "Selected file's name is: " '& vrtSelectedItem = Right(vrtSelectedItem, Len(vrtSelectedItem) - InStrRev(vrtSelectedItem, "\"))

    Next


'MsgBox "Selected File's name is: " & vrtSelectedItem

End With

End Sub
```

You will notice that I have commented out the line:

```
'MsgBox "Selected file's name is: " '& vrtSelectedItem = Right(vrtSelectedItem, Len(vrtSelectedItem) - InStrRev(vrtSelectedItem, "\"))
```

which strips out the path because when, I use it it returns the word 'false' also noteworthy is that when I set .AllowMultiSelect to false and only bring in a single value it works fine and I get just the file name. Can anyone see what is wrong? Here is the code for a single variable that works.

```
Sub GetfileNames()

Dim fd As FileDialog

dialogTitle = "Select files for Master Update."

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant


With fd
    .InitialFileName = "H:\jpmDesk\Desktop\Workforce Project Documents\Update Sandbox\"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Clear
    .Title = dialogTitle
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails

'This MSG is displayed if the user dose not select a file
        If .Show = False Then
            MsgBox "Files not selected to update. Process Terminated"
            Exit Sub
        End If

    vrtSelectedItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    vrtSelectedItem = Right(vrtSelectedItem, Len(vrtSelectedItem) - InStrRev(vrtSelectedItem, "\"))


MsgBox "Selected File's name is: " & vrtSelectedItem

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using ***Split()***

```
Sub GetTheName()
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
    s1 = "C:\financial\archive\2013\taxes\FirstQuarter.xlsm"
    ary = Split(s1, "\")
    s2 = ary(UBound(ary))
    MsgBox s2
End Sub
```